# Getting unexpected output with error

Tags: c

Writing this method with the following criteria..

INPUT: aabbb OUTPUT: a2b3

INPUT: ab    OUTPUT: ab (because its shorter than a1b1)

INPUT: a23   OUTPUT: error (does not read digits)

Here is the current method I have for this.

```
void encrypt(char* crypt, const char* source) {


    while (1) {

        char tmp = *source;

        if (!tmp) {
            *crypt = 0;
            printf("error\n");
            return;
        }

        size_t count = 1;
        while (*(++source) == tmp){
            if(isdigit(tmp)){
                printf("error\n");
                return;
            }
            ++count;
        }
        *(crypt++) = tmp;
        crypt += sprintf(crypt, "%zu", count);
    }

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

   if (argc != 2) {
      fprintf(stderr, "error\n");
      return 1;
   }

   const char* source = argv[1];

   char* crypt = malloc(strlen(source)*2+1);

   encrypt(crypt, source);
   printf("%s\n", crypt);
//   free(crypt);
   return 0;

}
```

Very oddly, every time I run this, I get the output:

```
./prog abbbb
error
a1b4

./prog a23r
error
a1
```

Why is this error occuring? How can I make it so that the first error message stops coming up, and why is the program not breaking when there are numbers in the middle of the inputted string?

Comment: This program is perfectly suited for a debugger.

Comment: I honestly, and very embarrassingly don't know how to use a debugger properly and I am using a remote machine through ssh and vim

Comment: You need a path that ends normally when the string ends.

Comment: You can run the debugger remotely as well. Take it as an opportunity to learn how to use it. Alternatively you can set up a local environment as well.

Comment: Why is the first error fprintf an error? That looks like a normal exit condition. It's going to occur every time you hit the character array terminator (null).

Comment: What should `if (!tmp)` be telling you? If it doesn't point anywhere, what happens when you dereference it? See [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and talk to the duck... Really, it helps `:)`